PC keeps restarting
I just built a new computer but for some reason the PCc always turns off and on with the GPU installed. It was during the very start of Windows 10 install, and I was very irritated. After a bit of troubleshooting I started the PC without the GPU, and I finally managed to install Windows. I thought that the GPU was faulty and so I brought a new low profile GPU. But the same problem happened again! And now, the computer always restarts automatically even without a GPU and it was said that  Windows didn't start properly.
Can you tell me what part was wrong? For some information I brought the RAM, SSD and PSU new. And here are my pc specs:

CPU: Intel Core i5 3500
Mobo: Biostar H61
RAM 16GB DDR3
SSD: SATA 256GB
HDD: Toshiba SATA 1TB
PSU: 600W


We can't really. You'll need to go through each part of the PC hardware and carefully disconnect, inspect, and reconnect it.
